# WP Вывод категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть таксономия с категориями которая выглядит подобным образом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
где Кухни и Шкафы - родительские категории, а остальное - подкатегории.
Как совершить вывод только родительских категорий ? 
А так же каким образом потом вывести подкатегории после перехода по категории. 
Пытался выводить и оно просто выводит всё сразу.

Есть post_type = 'furniture'.
У него taxonomy = 'category'.

На главной странице есть вывод категорий.

```
<?php
$cats = get_terms([
                  'taxonomy'   => 'category',
                  'hide_empty' => false,
                  'parent' => 0,
              ]);
          foreach ($cats as $cat) :   
?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->term_id, 'category') ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

ссылка выглядит как /category/term-id/
При клике происходит переход на category.php шаблон.
В нём пытаюсь выводить подкатегории

```
 $cats = get_terms( [
              'taxonomy' => 'category',
              'parent' => get_queried_object_id();,

         ] );
```

Если пытаться ставить parent => 0 - оно выводит только 'Кухни'

Comment: $categories = get_terms( 
   'category', 
    array('parent' => 0)
); получим все родительские категории, т.е. у котрых родителя нет

Comment: Вы хотите вывести это в админке?

Comment: @WPPunk нет, на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения всех родительских категорий нужно подставить `parent = 0` в запросы.

Самый простой способ это использовать шорткод `product_categories`:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[product_categories parent=0]' );
```

Чтобы получить все категории используйте get_terms

```
$product_cats = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'parent'   => 0
] );
```

Чтобы получит подкатегории конкретной категории вместо `parent` нужно подставить `get_queried_object_id`().

```
echo do_shortcode( '[product_categories parent=' . get_queried_object_id() . ']' );
$product_cats = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'parent'   => get_queried_object_id()
] );
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало, да. 
Теперь вопрос стоит в том, как подкатегории это категории при переходе в неё. Я создал файл 'taxonomy-category.php' - я так полагаю оно должно быть шаблоном для ссылок этой таксономии.

Comment: поясню точнее. в ссылку я указываю $term_id и перехожу по ссылке, например: '/category/kuhni' . taxonomy-category.php не работает в данном случае почему-то.

Comment: Обновил ответ с примером для подкатегорий

Comment: по какой-то из причин - оно не хочет выводить подкатегории. Оно возвращает пустой массив

Comment: Вы в файле taxonomy-category.php выводите? А как таксономия называется?

Comment: Я уже разрешил эту проблему. Как-то потыкал на иерархиям вывода. Сначала выводил в archives.php, потом попробовал в category.php и каким-то образом это заработало. Хотя я делал таксономию с названием 'category'

Comment: category уже зарегистированная таксономия для постов

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблему.
Вывод дочерних категорий.

```
 <?php
            $taxonomy = 'category';
            $term = get_queried_object();

            $children = get_terms( 
              $term->taxonomy, array(
                'parent' => $term->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => false
              )
            );
            print_r ($term);

            foreach ($children as $subcat) :   

?>

          <span><?php echo $subcat -> name ?></span>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
```